# How to determine label and features in logistic regression spark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I am using spark mlib, and doing classification using Logistic regression model. I followed this link:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#logistic-regression

```
 import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression;
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

// Load training data
Dataset<Row> training = spark.read().format("libsvm")
  .load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt");

LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8);

// Fit the model
LogisticRegressionModel lrModel = lr.fit(training);

// Print the coefficients and intercept for logistic regression
System.out.println("Coefficients: "
  + lrModel.coefficients() + " Intercept: " + lrModel.intercept());

// We can also use the multinomial family for binary classification
LogisticRegression mlr = new LogisticRegression()
        .setMaxIter(10)
        .setRegParam(0.3)
        .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
        .setFamily("multinomial");

// Fit the model
LogisticRegressionModel mlrModel = mlr.fit(training);
```

I am not sure how this model identify label and features if i am taking .csv as input? can anyone explain it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i was able to fix it, i need to use `VectorAssembler` or `StringIndexer` transformer, and there i have s`etInputCol`, `setOutputCol` method which provides way for setting label and features.

```
VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
                          .setInputCols(new String[]{"Lead ID"})
                          .setOutputCol("features");

sparkSession.read().option("header", true).option("inferSchema","true").csv("Book.csv");    
        dataset = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("Status").setOutputCol("label").fit(dataset).transform(dataset);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you load libsvm fromat data,it consists of label index1:value1 index2:value2......
If you use .csv,you must specify parmeters obviously.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So if input is libsvm it takes first column as label right and remaining as features? And how do we set label and features if input file is .csv

Comment: training = spark.read().format("csv").load("datapath");                              Or training = spark.read().csv("datapath");

Comment: Thanks,  but where i am setting label and features in given line ?

Comment: setLabelCol("label")
setPredictionCol("prediction")

Comment: when i give string type as input to setLabelCol, it gives IllegalArgumentException, so do we always need to to transform it using Stringindexer and then set it as label ?